# SequelizeJS primaryKey related include

Tags: node.js, rest, express, django-rest-framework, sequelize.js

I am currently working on a REST API, working with SequelizeJS and Express.

I'm used to Django Rest Framework and I'm trying to find a similar function :
I have a table User and a table PhoneNumber.
I want to be able to return a user in JSON, including the list of the primarykeys of its phone numbers like this :

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "phoneNumbers": [23, 34, 54],
}
```

Is there a way to do this simply and efficiently in sequelize or do I have to write functions that transform the fields like :

```
"phoneNumbers": [
    { "id": 23, "number": "XXXXXXXXXX" },
    { "id": 34, "number": "XXXXXXXXXX" },
    { "id": 54, "number": "XXXXXXXXXX" }
      ]
```

into what I have above ?

Thank you,
Giltho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize finder-methods accept and option `attribute` that lets you define which properties of a model it should query for. See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#attributes

That works for joins too:

```
User.all({
  include: [
    { model: Phonenumber, attributes: ['id']}
  ]
})
.then(function(users) {
})
```

will execute

```
SELECT user.*, phonenumber.id FROM user INNER JOIN phonenumber ON ...
```

But to turn the phonenumbers into an array of integers `[1,2,...]` in your api response, you'd still have to map the ids manually into an array, otherwise you get an array of `[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2},...]`.

But actually i **recommend not** to do that. An array of objects is the more future-proof option than an array of integers. Because your api-client don't need to change anything if you decide some day to expand the phonenumber object with additional attributes.